# java variables with no volatile, what about the consistency when a thread modifies the variable in cpuA and switch to cpuB

Tags: java, volatile

try this code block in one thread

```
int a = 0;

a = 1; //the thread is running on cpu A

a?   //the thread is switched and running on cpu B
```

so a can be 0 ?

Comment: Is `a` _shared_? How is it updated  and by what threads? Without proper notation this is highly bad question

Answer (score 0):

No, `a` must be 1 because there is a [happens-before relationship](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) between the assignment `a = 1` and the value of `a` being read later by the same thread.

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Comment: When a context switch happens, either the value of  `a` is written back to heap, or its value is stored in the process control block. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774550/is-processor-cache-flushed-during-context-switch-in-multicore

Comment: so the system needs to track all the variables that the thread modified?

Comment: if there are two thread switched, they both write 'a' back to heap?  it seems the happens-before does not work

Comment: Yes but typically it doesn't track individual variables because a variable is a programmer concept. Instead the memory management unit tracks [cache lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence). On the other hand, the variable may be stored in a register, and not be present on the heap at all.

Comment: In your code, `a` is a local variable. That means each thread has a copy of its own of `a`.

Comment: I see "So, cores must flush the caches whenever context is switched"

Comment: rectified, sorry,  'a' is not a local variable

Comment: If `a` is shared between two threads that both read and write values, you get fewer guarantees about the run time behavior.